# Display a blank instead of a 0 on a table on Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to develop a report with a table that includes several dimensions and displays a sales revenue measure. Most of the times this measure throws a zero, but the user wants to visualize a blank space instead. I have searched around, but I couldn´t find anything that gives me support. So if anyone has experimented this or found a workaround I would thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a IF condition to replace 0 with blanks. For example, if you are summarizing a field called "Sales" the following formula would work:

```
Measure = IF(Sum(Sales)=0,"",Sum(Sales))
```

Hope this helps.

Adding the additional option based on Ricardo's suggestion:

```
Measure = IF(Sum(Sales)=0,Blank(),Sum(Sales))
```

Comment: You can use Blank() as a function. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/blank-function-dax

Answer (score 0):

If you have a measure `[Measure]` and you want to replace `0` with a blank, you can do the following:

```
MeasureReplaceBlank = 
VAR Measure = [Measure]
RETURN IF ( Measure = 0, BLANK(), Measure )
```

Note that since I stored the calculation of `[Measure]` as a variable, I don't need to call it twice (once for the condition and once for the `True` branch of the `IF` function).